# Decimal Long Division

Tags: math-mode, packages

Does anyone know of a package or macro that handles decimal long division?  For example, I want to convert 3/8 to a decimal and show all of the steps.  I found a macro for longdiv that works great for integers, but was wondering if anyone knew of something that worked with decimals.  If this doesn't exist yet, how would I go about writing something to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a french presentation (options for other countries will be in the next version 0.3):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xlop}

\begin{document}
\opdiv{3}{8}  

\opdiv{22}{7} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Shane I have some problems with the english language so perhaps I don't take the good way

Comment: This is really cool - I am hoping to have an English version at some point - do you know when the version will be ready?  Thanks!

Comment: I can ask the author I know. There is a  documentation in English.

Comment: That would be awesome - thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Altermundus is there a version that looks like 3)`3`````?

Comment: @azetina What do you mean by 3)?

Comment: @Altermundus look at this [link](http://www.math-aids.com/images/division-worksheets-long.png). I wanted to post a new question but this one popup when typing it.

Comment: @azetina For me no but I'm not sure. There are a lot of new packages each day