# Polynomial Long Division over GF(p)

Tags: math-mode

Is there a package like polynom for typesetting polynomial long division but over a finite field such as GF(2). If not, how to manually typeset long division in general?

Thanks.

Addendum:

I attempted the following solution! However, the vertical spacing between each line and exponents of the equation below it is quite small, how to increase it? I tried \vspace but received errors. Thanks.

[image]

```
\[
\begin{array}{m{3.5em}ccccccccc}
&    &    &    &    &+x^4&+x^3&    &  &+1\\
\cline{2-10}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{x^3+x+1\big)}
     &+x^7&+x^6&+x^5&    &    &+x^2&+x&  \\
&    &+x^7&    &+x^5&+x^4&    &    &  &  \\
\cline{3-6}
&    &    &+x^6&    &+x^4&    &    &  &  \\
&    &    &+x^6&    &+x^4&+x^3&    &  &  \\
\cline{4-7}
&    &    &    &    &    &+x^3&+x^2&+x&  \\
&    &    &    &    &    &+x^3&    &+x&+1\\
\cline{7-10}
&    &    &    &    &    &    &+x^2&  &+1\\
\end{array}
\]
```

Comment: @Weaam Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14634/decimal-long-division. If this answers your question please add a comment so that this post can be treated as duplicate and redirect future users to the correct page.

Comment: @Yiannis: Thank you, but I don't see how it is relevant. I also checked the documentation for the xlop package but I couldn't see how it is of any use here. If it were useful, then a non-trivial explanation is needed!

Comment: @Yannis: The linked question is neither about polynomials nor about arithmetic in finite fields.

Comment: @Weaam @Caramdir Sorry! Read the question too quickly. Try this http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/polynom/polynom.pdf. Can you post an image or a link with an example of what you want to typeset?

Comment: @Yiannis: I do appreciate your efforts but please do read my question carefully once more, I do mention polynom. I also don't believe my question is vague, this is pretty standard! Thank you.

Comment: @Yiannis: Why did you use a mirror in your url? It is potentially shutdown.

Comment: Here's the [CTAN link for the `polynom` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/polynom)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't such a package to do calculations over finite fields. Arithmetic over finite fields GF(p^n) may be too complex for TeX. GF(2) and GF(p) are much easier, but there seems no such a package either.

To typeset long division manually, you can simply use an `array`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
x^3 - x + 1 = (x-1)(x^2+x) + 1 \in \mathbb{F}_3[x]
\]

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{*2r @{\hskip\arraycolsep}c@{\hskip\arraycolsep} *4r}
  &    &&    &  1 &  1 & 0 \\
\cline{3-7}
1 & -1 &\big)& 1 &  0 & -1 & 1 \\
  &    &&  1 & -1 \\
\cline{4-6}
  &    &&    &  1 & -1 \\
  &    &&    &  1 & -1 \\
\cline{5-7}
  &    &&    &    &    & 1 \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need a lot of these long divisions, it is worth to write a program (not necessarily in TeX) to generate the code. It's not very difficult for polynomials over GF(p).

---

For edited question:

To increase the vertical space between array lines, you can redefine the factor `\arraystretch` as showed above. Or you can use `makecell` package to add a gap.

Comment: Can we change `\big)` to a vertical line that perfectly touches the horizontal line?

Comment: @xport: Yes, you can use `\vline` here. And `\Big)` is also better.

Comment: +1 @Leo: one more, how to make the width of all columns equal?

Comment: @xport: Use `p{1cm}`, `tabularx`'s `X`, or `\makebox[1cm]{...}`, or any other method.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Leo's answer but I

- removed one column.
- replaced the `\big)` with a vertical rule.
- made all rows have equal width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\x}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|r}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
x^3 - x + 1 = (x-1)(x^2+x) + 1 \in \mathbb{F}_3[x]
\]

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}% specify the vertical stretch
\begin{array}{*{6}{>{\hfill}m{7mm}}}%specify the column width
&
    &
        &
            1&
                1&
                    0\\\cline{3-6}
1&
    -1&
        \x{1}&
                0&
                    -1&
                        1\\
&
    & 
        1&
            -1&
                &
                    \\\cline{3-5}
&
    &
        &
            1&
                -1&
                    \\
&
    &
        &
            1&
                -1&
                    \\\cline{4-6}
&
    &
        &
            &
                &
                    1\\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is quite useful, I was wondering about how to do that too. I think if using ")" showed inconsistencies, I'll follow this convention. Thank you.

Comment: @Weaam: I just updated this answer. Please see, all columns have equal width.

Comment: Great. But I must work with variable (a matter of convention) and therefor I wouldn't consider setting all columns with equal width. Thanks again, truly appreciate it!

Comment: @xport as per your suggestion, all minus symbols are changed to hyphen character, is it possible to fix?