# How to make equal width columns?

Tags: tables, arrays

[Based on Leo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21246/polynomial-long-division-over-gfp/21282#21282) but I removed one column and replaced the `\big)` with a vertical rule. Now I want to make all columns have the same width. How to do this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
x^3 - x + 1 = (x-1)(x^2+x) + 1 \in \mathbb{F}_3[x]
\]

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{*{6}{r}}
&
    &
        &
            1&
                1&
                    0\\\cline{3-6}
1&
    -1&
        \multicolumn{1}{|r}{1}&
                                0&
                                    -1&
                                        1\\
&
    & 
        1&
            -1&
                &
                    \\\cline{3-5}
&
    &
        &
            1&
                -1&
                    \\
&
    &
        &
            1&
                -1&
                    \\\cline{4-6}
&
    &
        &
            &
                &
                    1\\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

I got the solution by using `\begin{array}{*{6}{>{\hfill}m{1cm}}}`, but is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer, but it's a question of taste, the following:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\hbox to #1\bgroup\hfill$}c<{$\egroup}}

...
\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\newcommand\x[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|r}{#1}} % just not to clutter the array
\begin{array}{*{6}{R{1.5em}}}
  &    &       & 1  &  1 & 0 \\\cline{3-6}
1 & -1 & \x{1} & 0  & -1 & 1 \\
  &    &    1  & -1 &    &   \\\cline{3-5}
  &    &       &  1 & -1 &   \\
  &    &       &  1 & -1 &   \\\cline{4-6}
  &    &       &    &    & 1 
\end{array}
\]
```

The syntax `\hbox to <dimen>` is low level TeX, which is generally not recommended in LaTeX because it can have disastrous effects on color management. However, since this is done at the start at the cell, it should not be a problem. The construction `\hbox to 1.5em{\hfil x}` is similar to `\makebox[1.5em][r]{x}`, but it can be split into two parts: `\hbox to 1.5em\bgroup` at the beginning and `\egroup` at the end, so the "argument" can be gathered with **array**'s syntax.

A similar setup can be obtained by

```
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash$}p{#1}<{$}}
```

Comment: Are you sure it can be compiled?

Comment: Sorry, there was a missing brace; I almost always miss one when I use `*{n}{cols}`. `:-(`

Comment: what is `to`? It does not get rendered on the output.

Comment: Actually I want to check both Herbert's and your answers. Explaining `to` makes it a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\[ x^3 - x + 1 = (x-1)(x^2+x) + 1 \in \mathbb{F}_3[x] \]

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{*6{R{1em}}}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`, you have a key `columns-width`. When this key is used with the value `auto`, all the columns of the array have the same width, equal to the width of the widest cell of the array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
x^3 - x + 1 = (x-1)(x^2+x) + 1 \in \mathbb{F}_3[x]
\]

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{NiceArray}{rrrrrr}[columns-width=auto]
&
    &
        &
            1&
                1&
                    0\\\cline{3-6}
1&
    -1&
        \multicolumn{1}{|r}{1}&
                                0&
                                    -1&
                                        1 \\
&
    & 
        1&
            -1&
                &
                    \\\cline{3-5}
&
    &
        &
            1&
                -1&
                    \\
&
    &
        &
            1&
                -1&
                    \\\cline{4-6}
&
    &
        &
            &
                &
                    1\\
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]