# Better way to display long division?

Tags: formatting

I'm currently in the process of trying to create a worksheet for my students with long division problems for them to practice. Unfortunately, the best I've been able to come up with so far in terms of displaying long division like how they write it is:

[image: example]

Which could work if need be, but I thought I'd see if anyone has tooled around with this and come up with something better. To create that, all I did was type:

```
$\overline{)12345}$
```

Any suggestions for ways of making that better (so it looks more like what'd you see when using `\longdiv`) would be awesome.

Comment: I'm not somewhere I can check, but if I remember correctly, kicking up the parenthesis by one size improves the appearance.  a solution was published in tugboat years ago.

Comment: To add to Barbara's comment: here is what I did: \newcommand[2]{\longdiv}{#1\ \overline{\smash{\Big)}\ #2}} and it closed the gap.

Comment: Using `\overline`generally does not produce pretty results with shorter characters.  This applies to many of the answers given below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can give a definition of a command inspired by the one used in `longdiv.sty`; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\Mydiv[2]{%
$\strut#1$\kern.25em\smash{\raise.3ex\hbox{$\big)$}}$\mkern-8mu
        \overline{\enspace\strut#2}$}

\begin{document}

\Mydiv{56}{3678}\quad\Mydiv{3}{37678}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Gonzalo_Medina Thanks for the answer, how would I write numbers on top of the line?

Comment: Never mind, like this: `$$
\begin{array}{r}
0 \\
\Mydiv{8}{3}
\end{array}$$` and remove all the `$` from the command :)

Comment: Nice looking long division symbol... now, please convince the owner of polynom package to fix it so long division doesn't negate all the products on each line. :D

Answer (score 28):

`\smash` the right paren, so that it doesn't push up the `\overline`:``

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\showdiv[1]{\overline{\smash{)}#1}}
\begin{document}
\(\showdiv{12345} \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't like the curvature of the right paren, you can squeeze it a bit (here, I squeezed it perhaps a bit too much, to 50% of its original width, just to demonstrate)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\showdiv[1]{\overline{\smash{\hstretch{.5}{)}}#1}}
\begin{document}
\(\showdiv{12345} \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you are concerned that squeezing the glyph horizontally makes the stroke too thin, then just nearly overlay two of them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\showdiv[1]{\overline{\smash{\hstretch{.5}{)}\mkern-3.2mu\hstretch{.5}{)}}#1}}
\begin{document}
\(\showdiv{12345} \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

And, to add the finishing touches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\showdiv[1]{\overline{\smash{\hstretch{.5}{)}\mkern-3.2mu\hstretch{.5}{)}}#1}}
\let\ph\phantom
\begin{document}
\setstackgap{S}{1.5pt}
\stackMath\def\stackalignment{r}
\(
\stackunder{%
  5 \stackon[1pt]{\showdiv{12345}}{2469}%
}{%
  \Shortstack[l]{{\underline{10}} \ph{1}23 {\ph{1}\underline{20}} \ph{12}34 {\ph{12}\underline{30}} %
   \ph{123}45 {\ph{123}\underline{45}} \ph{1234}0}%
}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 24):

I got really prefectionisty about this once upon a time, and created a tikz-based solution:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\longdivision}[2]{
    \settowidth{\dividendlength}{#1}
    \settowidth{\divisorlength}{#2}
    \settoheight{\dividendheight}{#1}
    \settoheight{\maxheight}{#1#2}
    \settoheight{\divisorheight}{#2}

    \begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=.5pt]
        \node at (-.5*\divisorlength-1pt,.5*\divisorheight) {#2};
        \node at (.5*\dividendlength+5pt,.5*\dividendheight) {#1};
        \draw [thick]  (0pt,-.22*\dividendheight) arc (-70:60:\maxheight*.41 and \maxheight*.82) -- ++(\dividendlength+7pt,0pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newlength{\dividendlength}
\newlength{\divisorlength}
\newlength{\dividendheight}
\newlength{\divisorheight}
\newlength{\maxheight}

\begin{document}

\longdivision{$x^2+3x-5$}{$x-3$}

\end{document}
```

[image: polynomial long division]

I'm sure it could be improved upon, but I was happy enough with this (and never was happy with the paren + overline solutions).

Comment: I'm going to steal this and put it in my package `longdivision.sty` (with reference to this post of course) unless anyone has an objection. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I combined several ideas from the other answers on this page with some from [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21246/polynomial-long-division-over-gfp) to write long division for generating power series.

It's not perfect, but it's good enough for my purposes. Here's the Fibonacci sequence:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}

\newcommand{\longdiv}{\smash{\mkern-0.43mu\vstretch{1.31}{\hstretch{.7}{)}}\mkern-5.2mu\vstretch{1.31}{\hstretch{.7}{)}}}}
\begin{document}

\[
\arraycolsep=1pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{*1r @{\hskip\arraycolsep}c@{\hskip\arraycolsep} *{11}r}
        &          & 1 & + & x & + & 2x^2 & + & 3x^3 & + & 5x^4 & + & \dots  \\
\cline{2-13}
1-x-x^2 & \longdiv & 1 &   &   &   &      &   &      &   &      &   &        \\
        &          & 1 & - & x & - &  x^2 &   &      &   &      &   &        \\
\cline{3-7}
        &          &   &   & x & + &  x^2 &   &      &   &      &   &        \\
        &          &   &   & x & - &  x^2 & - &  x^3 &   &      &   &        \\
\cline{5-9}
        &          &   &   &   &   & 2x^2 & - &  x^3 &   &      &   &        \\
        &          &   &   &   &   & 2x^2 & - & 2x^3 & - & 2x^4 &   &        \\
\cline{7-11}
        &          &   &   &   &   &      &   & 3x^3 & + & 2x^4 &   &        \\
        &          &   &   &   &   &      &   & 3x^3 & - & 3x^4 & - & 3x^5   \\
\cline{9-13}
        &          &   &   &   &   &      &   &      &   & 5x^4 & + & 3x^5   \\
        &          &   &   &   &   &      &   &      &   &      &   & \vdots \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Best typesetting of all the answers. But keeping track of all those &'s is not easy.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `longdiv` "package". I put package in quotes because loading it using `\usepackage{}` doesn't work and for whatever reason, you have to load it using `\input longdiv.tex`.

Then you can do long division using `\longdiv{6584}{28}`.

After that, you can use package `polynom` to do polynomial long division as `\polylongdiv{x^2+2x+4}{x-1}`

Answer (score 3):

there is packaged named "longdivision". it works perfect for this purpose.

Longdivision package provides two commands: \longdivision and \intlongdivision.

if we write
\intlongdivision{12345}{13} we get this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One use case with minimal features (might need to play around with the exact numbers):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  $x+1\scalebox{1.2}{)}\hspace{-0.35em}\overline{\hspace{0.5em} x^2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you make your example compilable, so people can just copy/paste to try it.

Comment: Good call. All fixed.

Comment: Thanks :-) Note that `\scalebox` is provided by `graphicx`, so you don't need all of Ti*k*Z to use it. I edited it for you.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know why it needed tikz just that it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found that one can adjust the spacing using `\text{ }` spaces:

```
\begin{align*}
&\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }670\\
3 &\overline{\big)2011}\\
&\underline{\text{ }18}\\
&\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }21\\
&\text{ }\text{ }\underline{\text{ }21}\\
&\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }1
\end{align*}
```

[image]

You can tweak the spacing and the numbers for different long divisions. I scaled up the size of the parentheses to make it look better, as barbara beeton commented on the question.

Answer (score 0):

What about `polynom` package. If you write

```
\longdiv{12345}{13}
```

You obtain
[image]

Comment: It's not working for me.