# Division hut symbol

Tags: math-operators

Is there a way to make the division symbol for long division? I am trying to write a long division problem and need the symbol that the divisor goes under.
The symbol looks like a rectangle with only the left and top lines.

Comment: What is this symbol, exactly?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This question should help: [Better way to display long division?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131125/579)

Comment: Perhaps try the longdivision package, which computes out completely the long division steps and displays them, in formats associated with several different countries.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my answer can satisfy your needs using the package [`xlop`](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/macros/generic/xlop/doc/xlop-doc-fr.pdf). See this MWE code for example, of a symbol with a long division.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{xlop}
\begin{document}
\opdiv[displayintermediary=all,voperation=top]
{1353}{435}
\end{document}
```