# How can I show base-2 long division?

Tags: diagrams, calculations

I am writing a report in Latex and need to represent the CRC computation. So basically, I need to show the Paper-n-Pencil Method of Long Division in LaTeX.

Any idea how I can approach this problem ? Any good reference would be highly appreciated.

I plan to write similar thing in LaTeX.

[image: CRC Computation]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am needing to do the exact same thing.

Comment: sorry, I couldn't do in latex atleast. I computed in the paper and developed it in inkscape

Comment: OK, well I found somewhat of a solution, which I will post here for others' reference. It's not elegant (have to do the division by hand) but good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [this article](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://www.tug.org/tugboat/hiw/hey-18n2.ps&usg=AFQjCNGdNAeMtMdOZX5uPrOSfREjbbnr9g), I ended up doing this:

```
\newdimen\digitwidth
\settowidth\digitwidth{0}
\def~{\hspace{\digitwidth}}


\def\divrule#1#2{%
\noalign{\moveright#1\digitwidth%
\vbox{\hrule width#2\digitwidth}}}
101\,\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}
10010 \\ \hline
\big)\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
1011110 \101 \\ \divrule{0}{7}
~~~111 \~~~101 \\ \divrule{3}{4}
~~~~100
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
```

You have to do the division by hand, then use '~'s for aligning the digits. For the little bars, do `\divrule{startPosition}{length}`.

Example output:
[image]

Comment: Thats so wonderful. I will try using the same approach. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 4):

I've never used it myself, but you might try [this package](http://ctan.org/pkg/longdiv). It would likely require modification for binary, though.

There is also [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14634/decimal-long-division).