# Is there a long division macro?

Tags: math-mode, macros

I want to do regular long division in latex.
See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division

Is there a latex macro for this ?

Edit: I actually want to use it in mathjax, is this possible ?

Comment: I don't think that any LaTeX packages work in MathJaX until its developers wrapped them there :-/

Comment: See also [Decimal Long Division](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14634) from the "Related" bar.

Comment: To be clear, you want some software that takes two parameters (the input numerator and denominator), and turns out an HTML representation of the long division that will look right when it occurs on a page with Mathjax enabled?

Comment: there is a mathjax compatible longdiv generator here: http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/mathml-long-division.html

Answer (score 5):

There is [longdiv](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longdiv), which is loaded with `\input` not `\usepackage`, as it is not LaTeX specific.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{longdiv}

\begin{document}

\longdiv{6000}{34}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [`xlop`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xlop) package is what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}

\begin{document}
\opdiv{6000}{34}

\opdiv[maxdivstep=3]{6000}{34}
\end{document}
```

[image]