# Displaying long division manually with some caveats

Tags: arrays

Due to odd circumstances, I need to present long division manually (in math mode). That is, without using a macro. Moreover, I cannot use `\multicolumn` or `\cline`. Normally, I would do:

```
\[
\begin{array}{cccc}
& 0. & 7 & 5 \\ \cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & 3. & 0 & 0 \\
& 2. & 8 & \\ \cline{2-3}
& & 2 & 0 \\
& & 2 & 0 \\ \cline{3-4}
& & & 0
\end{array}
\]
```

but is there a way to obtain similar results without `\multicolumn` or `\cline`? I'm also open to options using asymptote.

I'm not looking for a generator as they don't insert a 0 when the divisor does not go into the dividend. I'd like a manual way of doing this that looks half-way decent.

Comment: An explanation for why this breaks would be nice too!

Comment: @Close Voters: I would say just an edit is needed.  A solution for this that works in LaTeX would (likely) work with MathJax as well.

Comment: MathJax questions are generally considered off topic, but this one is a duplicate, anyway: [Is there a long division macro?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99840)

Comment: The duplicate questions get TeX answers (this is a TeX forum) but for something that works with mathjax you could look at http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/mathml-long-division.html

Comment: @moderators: I edited as the duplicates did not answer my question. And if MathJax is off-topic, please consider removing the tag and closing other MathJax questions as well.

Comment: Answer's to the question @AlanMunn points to need not, and in fact are not, answers to this question.  I regard Mathjax markup questions as on topic for this site (as opposed to ones about installation, or problems with this or that browser), so I've voted to reopen.

Comment: Cf. http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272/how-do-we-feel-about-mathjax-jsmath-other-spin-offs/2378#2378 - my opinion is pretty much what Martin Scharrer said there.

Comment: @CharlesStewart Reopened, now what ? :-P

Comment: I'm really not sure this can be regarded as on topic. I see no way to do what's desired without `\multicolumn` and `\cline` on the TeX side. Unfortunately, MathJax doesn't understand them. So what? This should go to a MathJax forum, because it isn't connected to TeX in any way.

Comment: @moderators: Reworded to remove any reference to MathJax.

Comment: @percusse - I would have said, put up an answer saying that Mathjax didn't seem able to support this within native Latex idiom, but now the question is different, and closed.  At least off-topic is a better close reason than duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

A feasible representation:

```
$$
\begin{array}{r}
      \underline{0.75} \\[-2pt]
  4 | 3.00 \\
      \underline{2.8\phantom{0}} \\
        20 \\
        \underline{\phantom{0.}20} \\
         0
\end{array}
$$
```

as rendered on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com):

[image]