# How to write Euclidean division

Tags: tables, math-mode

I tried to use the `tabular` but the `\hline` spread over the whole line (even under the 77).

[image]

Comment: Welcom to TeX.SX. Please show us a minimal example beginning with `\documentclass{` and ending with `\end{document}`. It is easier and faster for us to help you then.

Comment: see here [How can I draw a horizontal line spanning only some of the table cells?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8549/how-can-i-draw-a-horizontal-line-spanning-only-some-of-the-table-cells)

Comment: Maybe the `xlop` package will interest you. It performs arithmetic operations and it can display it like if you had written it by hand ([xlop on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xlop)).

Comment: ...something like this [How to make a traditional division](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113975/15717) as @remjg suggested

Comment: @remjg Thanks, Everything work fine with xlop. I suggest you convert your comment to an answer.